# Execute a sequential requests handling each one

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, recursion

I need send requests in sequence but stopping sequence when one returns error, i'm using $http provider from angular.

My code is this:

```sql
const steps = [
    { url: '/api/test/1' },
    { url: '/api/test/2' },
    { url: '/api/test/3' },
    { url: '/api/test/4' },
]

const executeStep = index => {
    // Validate step existence
    if (typeof steps[index] == 'undefined') return
    // Request
    $http({method: 'get', url: steps[index].url})
    .success(response => {
        if (!response.success) throw response
        executeStep(index+1)
    }).error(err => {
        console.error(err)
        alert('Error')
    })
}

executeStep(0)
```

My question is: Has a better way to do this job?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, very similar to yours, but without handling or adding index numbers, so it is a bit more clear.

```
const queue = [
  { url: '/api/test/1' },
  { url: '/api/test/2' },
  { url: '/api/test/3' },
  { url: '/api/test/4' },
];

function runQueue() {
  const req = queue[0];

  $http({method: 'get', url: req.url})
  .success(response => {
    console.log(response);
    queue.shift();
    if (queue.length > 0) {
     runQueue();
    }
  })
  .error(err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
}
```

**Solution using Bluebird Promises.**

Another good option can be (especially if your code is server-side nodejs) using of [bluebird Promise](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) library. 
That library is not very popular nowadays because Promises are supported natively almost everywhere. But still some methods are very useful. In you case [Promise.each method](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) will work perfectly.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird'); // or import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
const queue = [
      { url: '/api/test/1' },
      { url: '/api/test/2' },
      { url: '/api/test/3' },
      { url: '/api/test/4' },
    ];

Promise.each(queue, (req) => {
    return http$({method: 'get', url: req.url}).then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp);
        });
}).then(() => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
   console.error(err);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is promise chaining and recursion.

```js
const steps = [
    { url: '/api/test/1' },
    { url: '/api/test/2' },
    { url: '/api/test/3' },
    { url: '/api/test/4' },
]

const executeStep = index => {
    // Validate step existence
    if (typeof steps[index] == 'undefined') return true;
    // Request
    return $http({method: 'get', url: steps[index].url})
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.success) throw response
        return executeStep(index+1)
    })
}

executeStep(0)
  .then( () => console.log('all done'))
  .catch(e => console.error('something failed', e))
```

Here, every time a request is finished it returns back a new promise that contains the next request. That way `executeStep(0)` will be resolved only when every other promise has finished or it will be rejected immediately if any promise encounters an error.

Answer (score -1):

You can use async function in combination with promises for that.

```
const queue = [
  { url: '/api/test/1' },
  { url: '/api/test/2' },
  { url: '/api/test/3' },
  { url: '/api/test/4' },
];

function oneRequest(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        $http({method: 'get', url: req.url})
            .success(response => resolve(response))
            .error(err => reject(err));
    });
}

async function allRequests(reqs) {
    let resps = [];
    for(var i=0;i<reqs.length;i++) {
        let resp = await oneRequest(reqs[i]);
        resps.push(resp);
    }
    return resps;
}

allRequests(queue)
    .then(resps => console.log(resps))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```